# Ansible merge json object

Tags: ansible

I need to merge two JSON objects based on first object keys

```
object1 = {
 "params" : {
    "type": ["type1", "type2"],
    "requeststate": []
 }        
}

object2 = {
 "params" : {
    "type": ["type2", "type3", "type4"],
    "requeststate": ["Original", "Revised" ],
    "responsestate": ["Approved" ]
 }        
}
```

I need to merge two object based on first object key and my output should look like below

```
mergedobject = {
 "params" : {
    "type": ["type1", "type2", "type3", "type4"],
    "requeststate": ["Original", "Revised"]
 }        
}
```

i searched for my case and didnt find much details
Please let me know is it possible to do with ansible

I can able to merge array with

```
  set_fact:
    mergedrequeststate: "{{ object1.params.requeststate +  object2.params.requeststate  }}"
```

but my case involved with morethan 15 params object and I cant declare all the param object . Also it may grow in future and I need handle that if possible.

Please comment if you need more details.
Thanks for your support

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`combine`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) filter.

```
- set_fact:
    mergedobject: "{{ object1.params | combine (object2.params) }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

the requirement is well described, i would only add that you want to merge the keys and get the `unique` values from the 2 objects (if that's not the case, pay attention to the `union` filter in the PB below). Also, your example variables assume that the we want to merge the keys under `objectX.params`.

without further due, here is a PB that will get you going. there is 1 debug step to display all the keys your `object1.params` has, then a loop to merge the values of the 2 objects, then a final print.

PB:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    object1:
      params:
        type:
        - type1
        - type2
        requeststate: []
    object2:
      params:
        type:
        - type2
        - type3
        - type4
        requeststate:
        - Original
        - Revised
        responsestate:
        - Approved

  tasks:

  - name: print all the keys in the object1.params variable
    debug:
      msg: "{{ object1['params'].keys() | list }}"

  - name: for each key, merge from the 2 variables
    set_fact:
      mergedobj: "{{ mergedobj|default({}) | combine({item: object1['params'][item] | union(object2['params'][item]) }) }}"
    with_items:
    - "{{ object1['params'].keys() | list }}"

  - name: print final result
    debug:
      var: mergedobj
```

execution result:

```
[http_offline@greenhat-29 tests]$ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [print all the keys in the object1.params variable] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "type",
        "requeststate"
    ]
}

TASK [for each key, merge from the 2 variables] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=type)
ok: [localhost] => (item=requeststate)

TASK [print final result] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "mergedobj": {
        "requeststate": [
            "Original",
            "Revised"
        ],
        "type": [
            "type1",
            "type2",
            "type3",
            "type4"
        ]
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   

[http_offline@greenhat-29 tests]$
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

you should check out the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html), you can simply do:

```
- set_fact: 
    mergedobject: "{{ object1 | combine(object2, recursive=True) }}"
```